# android ANR in Native method ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame

Tags: android, android-source

I got loat of ANR error and Native Crash on a special device, other device is ok.

Its irregular， it will happend many times a day.

somethimes app restart and enter the MainAcitivty will be ANR.

I cant reconstruct on other same device.

ANR info has different reasons

- Broadcast of Intent
- Input dispatching timed out

infomation:

```
Cpu Information: 'abi: armeabi-v7a,armeabi/processor: -/hardware: Generic DT based system'
Mobile Information: 'model: G500/version: 8.1.0/sdk: 27'
Build fingerprint: 'rockchip/rk3288/rk3288:8.1.0/OPM8.190305.001/183714:user/release-keys'
Runtime Information: 'start: 20210929162644/maxheap: 536870912/primaryabi: armeabi-v7a/ground: fg'
kernel version: Linux version 4.4.132 (zim@softserver1) (gcc version 6.3.1 20170404 (Linaro GCC 6.3-2017.05) ) #95 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 7 10:19:20 CST 2020
```

error trace:

#### Broadcast of Intent

```
PID: 2264
Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50200014 (has extras) }
Load: 1.03 / 1.7 / 1.03
CPU usage from 245270ms to -1ms ago (2021-09-30 19:47:04.778 to 2021-09-30 19:51:10.049):
  20% 1682/mediaserver: 2.5% user + 17% kernel / faults: 858 minor
  16% 1684/surfaceflinger: 7.8% user + 8.4% kernel / faults: 97512 minor
  13% 1687/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 7.2% user + 6.5% kernel / faults: 128775 minor
  3.3% 1768/system_server: 2.1% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 17640 minor
  1.5% 33/ksmd: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
  1% 196/logd: 0.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 107 minor
  0.6% 311/kworker/u9:3: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
  0.6% 816/ksdioirqd/mmc1: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
  0.5% 166/kworker/u9:1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
  0.4% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
  0.3% 208/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 30 minor
  0.3% 40/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
  0.2% 862/RTW_CMD_THREAD: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.2% 225/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 216 minor
  0.2% 1648/kworker/u9:4: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.2% 167/kworker/u8:2: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.2% 168/kworker/u8:3: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.2% 164/kworker/u9:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.2% 143/mmcqd/2: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.1% 1646/kworker/u8:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 310/kworker/u9:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 1680/audioserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 178 minor
  0.1% 197/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1098 minor
  0.1% 334/media.codec: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1058 minor
  0.1% 1679/zygote: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2622 minor
  0.1% 99/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 1686/android.hardware.audio@2.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 66 minor
  0% 30/kconsole: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 209/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 54 minor
  0% 1683/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 867 minor
  0% 861/RTW_XMIT_THREAD: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 230/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 566 minor
  0% 198/hwservicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1503 minor
  0% 228/android.hardware.power@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 325/installd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 224 minor
  0% 315/f2fs_discard-25: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1685/wificond: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 140 minor
  0% 328/media.extractor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 312 minor
  0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 96/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 14/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 863/RTWHALXT: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 118 minor
  0% 216/android.hidl.allocator@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 235 minor
  0% 307/dmcrypt_write: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 24/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 174/ueventd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 46 minor
  0% 15/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 19/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 232/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1725/iptables-restore: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 291 minor
  0% 141/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 169/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 221/android.hardware.configstore@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
  0% 324/drmserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
  0% 326/keystore: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 64 minor
  0% 1726/ip6tables-restore: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 311 minor
 +0% 1898/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1914/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1990/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2031/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2094/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2100/kbase_event: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2145/kworker/u8:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2163/kworker/u8:4: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2174/kbase_event: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2187/kworker/3:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2192/com.hcdt.hcdtdataservice: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2203/android.process.media: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2221/com.android.smspush: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2233/com.android.hcdt.launcher: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2253/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2264/com.hd123.apos: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2299/com.android.printspooler: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2322/com.android.keychain: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2336/kbase_event: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2367/android.process.acore: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2383/com.android.managedprovisioning: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2407/com.android.onetimeinitializer: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2425/com.android.packageinstaller: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2443/com.android.providers.calendar: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2520/kbase_event: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2542/com.tencent.wxpayface: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2585/com.tencent.wxpayface.iotservice.core: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2638/com.uarmsoft.boxtest: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2781/kworker/u9:5: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2812/com.tencent.ilink.ServiceProcess: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2886/kbase_event: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 2920/android.ext.services: 0% user + 0% kernel
32% TOTAL: 17% user + 14% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.1% softirq

CPU usage from 50ms to 384ms later (2021-09-30 19:51:10.098 to 2021-09-30 19:51:10.432):
  52% 1768/system_server: 29% user + 23% kernel / faults: 373 minor
    32% 1784/ActivityManager: 9.8% user + 23% kernel
    16% 1777/HeapTaskDaemon: 16% user + 0% kernel
  9.7% 1682/mediaserver: 3.2% user + 6.4% kernel
    6.4% 2879/FFParser: 0% user + 6.4% kernel
    3.2% 2896/DecoderAudio: 0% user + 3.2% kernel
  11% 2542/com.tencent.wxpayface: 3.7% user + 7.4% kernel
    3.7% 2632/imiUSBHandleEve: 0% user + 3.7% kernel
    3.7% 2809/FaceEngine: 0% user + 3.7% kernel
  3.2% 816/ksdioirqd/mmc1: 0% user + 3.2% kernel
  3.2% 1684/surfaceflinger: 3.2% user + 0% kernel
17% TOTAL: 9.5% user + 7.9% kernel


"main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x73466978 self=0xa473d000
  | sysTid=2264 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa85354a4
  | state=? schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe59d000-0xbe59f000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:802)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

native stack:
Thread Name: 'com.hd123.apos'
pid: 2264, tid: 2264
  #00 pc 00018cf0  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01 pc 000476d3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL24__pthread_cond_timedwaitP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tbPK8timespec+102)
  #02 pc 00048aad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #03 pc 00048a49  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #04 pc 002219eb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat

--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
status:
Name:   com.hd123.apos
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   2264
Ngid:   0
Pid:    2264
PPid:   1679
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    10046   10046   10046   10046
Gid:    10046   10046   10046   10046
FDSize: 256
Groups: 3001 3002 3003 9997 20046 50046 
VmPeak:  2001168 kB
VmSize:  1972984 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:    404800 kB
VmRSS:    361900 kB
VmData:   328736 kB
VmStk:      8192 kB
VmExe:        20 kB
VmLib:    166996 kB
VmPTE:       710 kB
VmPMD:         0 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    80
SigQ:   0/15824
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000001200
SigIgn: 0000000000001000
SigCgt: 000000064001ccfe
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000000000000000
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
Mems_allowed:   1
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    14273
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 5885
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
memory info:
JavaMax:    524288 kB
JavaTotal:  17090 kB
JavaFree:   2002 kB
NativeHeap: 119040 kB
NativeAllocated: 116553 kB
NativeFree: 2481 kB
availMem:   1118272 kB
threshold:  147456 kB
lowMemory:  false
```

#### Input dispatching timed out

```
PID: 1820
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 4.  Wait queue head age: 6807.7ms.)
Load: 2.13 / 2.14 / 1.38
CPU usage from 220056ms to -1ms ago (2021-09-29 19:13:56.010 to 2021-09-29 19:17:36.066):
  19% 234/surfaceflinger: 9.6% user + 10% kernel / faults: 111327 minor
  15% 227/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 8.5% user + 7.3% kernel / faults: 148169 minor
  14% 334/mediaserver: 2.1% user + 12% kernel / faults: 2849 minor
  8.8% 1224/com.tencent.wxpayface: 2.6% user + 6.2% kernel / faults: 2262 minor
  3.2% 428/system_server: 2% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 28939 minor 7 major
  1.5% 33/ksmd: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
  0.5% 709/com.android.settings: 0.4% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 10273 minor 29 major
  0.9% 326/audioserver: 0.4% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 57 minor
  0.3% 931/com.android.hcdt.launcher: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11514 minor
  0.8% 218/android.hardware.audio@2.0-service: 0.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 228 minor
  0.8% 226/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service: 0% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 714 minor
  0.7% 1657/kworker/u9:1: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
  0.6% 558/com.android.systemui: 0.4% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2647 minor
  0.6% 197/logd: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 109 minor
  0.5% 1475/kworker/u9:5: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
  0.5% 317/kworker/u9:4: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
  0.4% 40/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
  0.4% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
  0.4% 546/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3169 minor
  0.4% 821/ksdioirqd/mmc1: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
  0.3% 6/kworker/u8:0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
  0.2% 1288/com.tencent.wxpayface.iotservice.core: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1810 minor
  0.2% 867/RTW_CMD_THREAD: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.2% 1662/kworker/u8:3: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.1% 312/kworker/u9:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 143/mmcqd/2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 1165/com.hd123.apos:channel: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 384 minor
  0% 1519/com.tencent.ilink.ServiceProcess: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 182 minor
  0% 319/f2fs_discard-25: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1689/kworker/u8:4: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 229/android.hardware.power@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
  0% 335/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 467 minor
  0% 30/kconsole: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 866/RTW_XMIT_THREAD: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1651/kworker/u8:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 167/kworker/u8:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 231/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 348 minor
  0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 20/kworker/2:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 896/android.process.media: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 167 minor
  0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 198/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 178 minor
  0% 337/wificond: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
  0% 4/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 868/RTWHALXT: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 24/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 14/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 309/dmcrypt_write: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 325/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 109 minor
  0% 615/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 58 minor
  0% 19/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 162/kworker/3:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 199/hwservicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 144 minor
  0% 233/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 316/kworker/3:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 338/media.codec: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 883/com.hcdt.hcdtdataservice: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 37 minor
  0% 1495/kworker/1:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1655/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1731/kworker/u9:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1732/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1741/kworker/2:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1753/kworker/u8:5: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1820/com.hd123.apos: 0% user + 0% kernel
 +0% 1888/kbase_event: 0% user + 0% kernel
32% TOTAL: 19% user + 12% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.1% softirq

CPU usage from 28ms to 355ms later (2021-09-29 19:17:36.093 to 2021-09-29 19:17:36.420):
  33% 428/system_server: 13% user + 19% kernel / faults: 209 minor
    33% 442/ActivityManager: 13% user + 19% kernel
  19% 334/mediaserver: 0% user + 19% kernel
    9.8% 1470/FFParser: 0% user + 9.8% kernel
    6.5% 1492/DecoderAudio: 0% user + 6.5% kernel
  14% 1224/com.tencent.wxpayface: 3.7% user + 11% kernel
    7.4% 1390/imiUSBHandleEve: 0% user + 7.4% kernel
    7.4% 1509/FaceEngine: 3.7% user + 3.7% kernel
    7.4% 1569/FaceEngine: 3.7% user + 3.7% kernel
  3% 40/cfinteractive: 0% user + 3% kernel
  3.1% 234/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 3.1% kernel
13% TOTAL: 5% user + 8.4% kernel

"main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x73466978 self=0xa6bbd000
  | sysTid=1820 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa9a54a4
  | state=? schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe5b5000-0xbe5b7000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:802)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

native stack:
Thread Name: 'com.hd123.apos'
pid: 1820, tid: 1820
  #00 pc 001ff41c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+24083)
  #01 pc 001da3ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+584)
  #02 pc 001deaa7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #03 pc 001f344d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
  #04 pc 003eaf75  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1080)
  #05 pc 003f2794  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
  #06 pc 001da2f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #07 pc 001deaa7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #08 pc 001f344d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
  #09 pc 003eb39d  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+184)
  #10 pc 003f2714  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #11 pc 001da2f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #12 pc 001deaa7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #13 pc 001f344d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
  #14 pc 003ec86b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+598)
  #15 pc 003f6314  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #16 pc 001da2f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #17 pc 001deaa7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #18 pc 001f344d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
  #19 pc 003ec86b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+598)
  #20 pc 003f6314  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #21 pc 001da2f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #22 pc 001de9f5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
  #23 pc 003dfb7f  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+934)
  #24 pc 004046f1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #25 pc 00a61923  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat

--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
status:
Name:   com.hd123.apos
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   1820
Ngid:   0
Pid:    1820
PPid:   325
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    10046   10046   10046   10046
Gid:    10046   10046   10046   10046
FDSize: 256
Groups: 3001 3002 3003 9997 20046 50046 
VmPeak:  2031684 kB
VmSize:  2006240 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:    414340 kB
VmRSS:    376836 kB
VmData:   348660 kB
VmStk:      8192 kB
VmExe:        20 kB
VmLib:    166996 kB
VmPTE:       704 kB
VmPMD:         0 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    96
SigQ:   0/15824
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000001200
SigIgn: 0000000000001000
SigCgt: 000000064001ccfe
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000000000000000
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
Mems_allowed:   1
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    2349
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 3442
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
memory info:
JavaMax:    524288 kB
JavaTotal:  20712 kB
JavaFree:   923 kB
NativeHeap: 116480 kB
NativeAllocated: 113591 kB
NativeFree: 2891 kB
availMem:   1080836 kB
threshold:  147456 kB
lowMemory:  false
```

#### other trace 1

```
"main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x73466978 self=0xa6bbd000
  | sysTid=1820 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa9a54a4
  | state=? schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe5b5000-0xbe5b7000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:802)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

native stack:
Thread Name: 'com.hd123.apos'
pid: 1820, tid: 1820
  #00 pc 00049534  /system/lib/libc.so (__ppoll+20)
  #01 pc 0001f7c1  /system/lib/libc.so (poll+48)
  #02 pc 00028e78  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #03 pc 0002a0b0  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #04 pc 000049b0  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #05 pc 0000c700  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #06 pc 000096b0  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #07 pc 00009a90  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #08 pc 00012c84  /data/app/com.hd123.apos-pXJDcgUemUeQc4cIvRdj8Q==/lib/arm/libcrashsdk.so
  #09 pc 0030a29c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space) (deleted)

--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
status:
Name:   com.hd123.apos
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   1820
Ngid:   0
Pid:    1820
PPid:   325
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    10046   10046   10046   10046
Gid:    10046   10046   10046   10046
FDSize: 256
Groups: 3001 3002 3003 9997 20046 50046 
VmPeak:  2057880 kB
VmSize:  1993160 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:    414340 kB
VmRSS:    356600 kB
VmData:   342592 kB
VmStk:      8192 kB
VmExe:        20 kB
VmLib:    166996 kB
VmPTE:       700 kB
VmPMD:         0 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    93
SigQ:   0/15824
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 00000000fffbfeff
SigIgn: 0000000000001000
SigCgt: 000000064001ccfe
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000000000000000
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
Mems_allowed:   1
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    2368
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 3445
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
memory info:
JavaMax:    524288 kB
JavaTotal:  25346 kB
JavaFree:   12300 kB
NativeHeap: 106240 kB
NativeAllocated: 100869 kB
NativeFree: 5371 kB
availMem:   1096152 kB
threshold:  147456 kB
lowMemory:  false
```

#### I also got some crash info

many crash has same summary. Is it too much DirectByteBuffer?

```
  286 of java.lang.Class (219 unique instances)
  181 of java.nio.DirectByteBuffer (170 unique instances)
   38 of java.lang.ref.WeakReference (38 unique instances)
   10 of android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver (10 unique instances)
    6 of android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$InnerConnection (6 unique instances)
    4 of android.content.ContentProvider$Transport (4 unique instances)
    4 of android.view.ViewRootImpl$W (4 unique instances)
    3 of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader (2 unique instances)
    3 of java.lang.String (3 unique instances)
    3 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper (3 unique instances)
    3 of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport (3 unique instances)
    3 of android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$DeathMonitor (3 unique instances)
    2 of android.opengl.EGLDisplay (1 unique instances)
    2 of android.opengl.EGLSurface (1 unique instances)
    2 of android.opengl.EGLContext (1 unique instances)
    2 of java.lang.ThreadGroup (2 unique instances)
    2 of android.os.Binder (2 unique instances)
    2 of android.view.autofill.AutofillManager$AutofillManagerClient (2 unique instances)
    2 of android.os.Handler$MessengerImpl (2 unique instances)
    1 of android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$SpellCheckerSessionListenerImpl
    1 of android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$InternalListener
    1 of org.android.spdy.SpdySession
    1 of org.android.spdy.SpdyAgent
    1 of java.lang.Runtime
    1 of dalvik.system.VMRuntime
    1 of android.media.PlayerBase$IPlayerWrapper
    1 of android.view.WindowManagerGlobal$1
    1 of android.hardware.input.InputManager$InputDevicesChangedListener
    1 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1
    1 of android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayManagerCallback
    1 of android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$1
    1 of android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
    1 of android.media.PlayerBase$IAppOpsCallbackWrapper
    1 of android.view.ThreadedRenderer$ProcessInitializer$1
```

## my conclusion

I cant find out the The real error.

- all error's NativeFree is low, Is it the native memory too low? out of memory?
- can rom developer solve the problem?

help me please.

Comment: Infinite loop? A dead lock? Debug your code then. Use `Log.d()`.